# 2 zoom effects on product image magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, image

I'm using magento 2.0.7, and I've noticed that on the product page, when I click the product image, I have 2 zoom effects, sometimes loads one, and sometimes the other.. just random.. both when clicking on. How can I keep just one of them? What file do I need to edit to find that functions? I'm not using any zoom extension.. but I'm using the Ves Yume theme.

```
<var name="gallery">
    <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
    <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
    <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
    <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
    <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
    <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
    <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
    <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
    <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
    <var name="transition">
        <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
        <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
    </var>
    <var name="fullscreen">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
        <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
        <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
        <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
        <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
        </var>
    </var>
</var>

<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">click</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>

<var name="breakpoints">
    <var name="mobile">
        <var name="conditions">
            <var name="max-width">767px</var>
        </var>
        <var name="options">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="navigation">dots</var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
</var>
```

Comment: Remember the magnifier tag refers to the full screen lightbox, not the zoom on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You can check image zoom function inside **view.xml** file,

You have to override view.xml file from **`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml`** to your theme **`app/design/Package/themename/etc/view.xml`**

You can find it using `<var name="gallery">` from view xml. all images related functions are display here.

Comment: This is what I got in my ../view.xml file  , edited in the post

Comment: Not good enough, you will need to give us the exact tag name to edit. Thanks.